# How can I do structured logging?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

Are there any logging libraries that allow for structured logging of objects, by which I mean, the output is in a structured form, such as JSON or XML?

At the application level, I want to use a terse syntax (logging tends to hide application code), such as

1. `logger.info("Deleting user", user)`
2. `logger.info(part("Deleting user", user), part("Account", account), part("Something else", someValue));`

At the log file level, I get well structured JSON (etc), with meta-data (thread, MDC, time, level, etc) as an envelope, with my own message as a structured JSON object within it, e.g.

```
"log" : {
  "time": <timestamp>,
  "level": "INFO",
  "thread": <thread-name>,
  "MDC": [MDC info added by application code],
  etc...
  "message": {
    "Message": "Deleting User",
    "User": <JSON object of the user serialised>
  }
}
```

Of course, it would not need to be pretty-printed in the log file.

It would be cool if the domain objects (e.g. User) could implement a `Loggable` interface that has methods to serialise state for different log-levels, e.g.

1. INFO level gives a summary
2. DEBUG level gives more, deeper data, recursively

***Some log aggregator could then make sense of the logs at a *semantic* level. Logs are consistently formatted allowing searching, etc.***

I have, in the past, implemented a couple of functions that get me part of the way, to ensure key/values pairs are formatted but that doesn't give me everything I want. This works, normalising key/values, formatting values, highlighting nulls, etc but it doesn't emit JSON and cannot delegate object formatting: -

```
logger.info(logString(part("Deleting user", user), part("Account", account), part("Something else", someValue)));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try https://github.com/michaeltandy/log4j-json

Comment: @DavidKerr you want to json String structured as like above you mansion ?

Comment: @MayankPandya that's a start, but it only puts the meta-data into JSON, it doesn't structuring my objects into JSON (the "message" part of my sample JSON).

Comment: @DavidKerr did you end up finding a satisfactory option? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSONObject.toString() method to pretty print the JSON on logcat.

```
Log.d("tag", jsonObject.toString(4));
```

Comment: But my object is just a plain domain object POJO. By default they logging code would just call 'toString' but if the domain object implements (for example) 'Loggable', then methods on it can turn the domain object into JSON

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem space addressed by [message templates](https://messagetemplates.org). The [serilogj](https://github.com/80dB/serilogj) implementation in Java looks like:

```
Log.information("Deleting {@user}", user);
```

where `@` indicates that the `user` property should be serialized into the event as structured data.

Even without serialization, message templates produce logs with first-class semantic properties. For example the event:

```
Log.information("Dividing {a} by {b}", 1, 0);
```

will produce an event with message *Dividing 1 by 0* and properties `a = 1` and `b = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/savoirtech/slf4j-json-logger

Usage example (output formatted for readability)

```java
logger.trace()
    .message("Report executed")
    .map("someStats", map)
    .list("customers", list)
    .field("year", "2016")
    .log();
```

```json
{
    "message":"Report executed",
    "someStats": { "numberSold":"0" },
    "customers": [ "Acme", "Sun" ],
    "year":"2016",
    "level":"TRACE",
    "thread_name":"main",
    "class":"com.savoirtech.logging.slf4j.json.logger.BasicLoggingTests",
    "logger_name":"com.savoirtech.logging.slf4j.json.logger.BasicLoggingTests",
    "@timestamp":"2016-08-18 12:17:56.308-0400"
}
```

The project is a bit old, though, its latest commit is from 2017.
I am not affiliated with this project, and I haven't used it, so I don't know how well this works.